# How can I configure multi domain IMAPS POPS and SMTPs with single SSL Certificate

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, ssl-certificate, imap, pop3

If I have 3 domains hosted on single linux based mail server that are domain1.com, domain2.com and domain3.com.and I have *.domain1.com signed ssl certificate.

Is there way I can use the same single ssl certificate for all domains for services POP3-SSL ,IMAP-SSL and SMTP-SSL.
or

Is there way to do url forwarding for pop,imap and smtp in DNS console by configuring somethind as below
**pop.domain2.com ==> pop.domain1.com

smtp.domain2.com --> smtp.domain1.com

imap.domain2.com --> imap.domain1.com

and

pop.domain3.com ==> pop.domain1.com

smtp.domain3.com--> smtp.domain1.com

imap.domain3.com--> imap.domain1.com**

Answer (score 1):

You need a cert with [Subject Alternative Names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubjectAltName) for all hostnames in question.

A wildcard certificate or any other method will not help you. This likely means you need to buy a new cert.